# How to escape square brackets in web forms?

Tags: webforms, 8

consider the following HTML element in (View) Source page

```
district:  
  '#type':select  
  '#title':District  
    '#attributes':  
       data-district: '[{Test!test!:Test!Test!}]'
```

To my suprise when I check the browser for data-district it is an empty string. So my question  is how to escape square brackets in  (View) Source page if they are placed at the beginning([) and end (]) of string

Answer (score 0):

The below YAML render the data-district attribute without any problems via the Bartik theme,

```
district:
  '#type': select
  '#title': District
  '#options':
    one: One
    two: Two
    three: Three
  '#attributes':
    data-district: '[{test!Test!}]'
```

Below is a screenshot of the output.

[image]

In your example, the #attributes YAML is indented incorrectly.

Comment: I now see the issue which is '[{Test!test!:Test!Test!}]' is being interpreted as a token because of the colon (:) and being removed.  Please create a ticket in the webform module's issue queue and we can fix it.

Comment: Here is the ticket. https://www.drupal.org/node/2920199

Comment: This issue has been fixed. Please download the latest dev release of the webform module to review.